# Why can't I open avi video in openCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, video-capture

I just wrote a simple video reading example with openCV2.3.1, but it seems that I cannot open avi video anyway :(

```cpp
VideoCapture capture("guitarplaying.avi");
if(!capture.isOpened()){
    std::cout<<"cannot read video!\n";
    return -1;
}
Mat frame;
namedWindow("frame");

double rate = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
int delay = 1000/rate;

while(true)
{
    if(!capture.read(frame)){
        break;
    }
    imshow("frame",frame);

    if(waitKey(delay)>=0)
        break;
}

capture.release();
```

I made a breakpoint in `std::cout<<"cannot read video!\n"` and find that it stopped here every time. So why avi video cannot be opened? Thanks!

Comment: AVI is a file format, not a video format. So you should check that the video is encoded in a supported video format, as an AVI file may be encoded in different ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)**
Make sure the video file is actually in the same folder as the application (I'm assuming you've already tried this), otherwise specify the absolute path.

**2)**
If you're on Windows, you may need a codec pack to read the video file (e.g., [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/klcp_update.htm)).

As Macmade suggested, AVI is merely a container which can house different audio, video, or even closed caption codecs. Also, [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) are Zeranoe's FFmpeg builds for Windows. You can get further information on your file's codec contents if you do the following:

```
ffmpeg -i guitarplaying.avi
```

You should see an output that looks like this:

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.7.git, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec  6 2011 09:20:43 with gcc 4.6.1
  configuration: --pkg-config=pkg-config --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable
-nonfree --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-memalign-hack --enable-postproc --a
rch=x86 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- --prefix=/home/wluc
as/ffmpeg-cross/build/deploy --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --en
able-bzlib --enable-libxvid --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvor
bis --enable-libtheora --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfreetype
  libavutil    51. 30. 0 / 51. 30. 0
  libavcodec   53. 40. 0 / 53. 40. 0
  libavformat  53. 24. 0 / 53. 24. 0
  libavdevice  53.  4. 0 / 53.  4. 0
  libavfilter   2. 51. 0 /  2. 51. 0
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '..\..\Videos\Sintel\sintel_trailer-720p
.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    title           : Sintel Trailer
    artist          : Durian Open Movie Team
    encoder         : Lavf52.62.0
    copyright       : (c) copyright Blender Foundation | durian.blender.org
    description     : Trailer for the Sintel open movie project
  Duration: 00:00:52.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1165 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720,
 1033 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 126
 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    :
```

So, as you can see this .mp4 container has a H.264 video codec and an AAC audio codec.

Comment: To expand on point 1: people often make the mistake of putting the image file (avi, jpg, etc.) in the same folder as their source code instead of the same folder as the compiled program.

Comment: This describes the problem, but not the solution. @nimcap's answer explains how to fix it concisely and accurately.

Comment: I copy the opencv_ffmpeg310.dll, opencv_ffmpeg310x64.dll  and the problem was solved. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 56):

A missing OpenCV's ffmpeg.dll does not generate any warnings/errors in OpenCV 2.3.1, and code fails silently. Make sure that you have proper opencv_ffmpeg*.dll in your path.

Comment: on windows you need to add the right folder like this: `opencv\build\..\bin` from where you extracted opencv to your path.

Answer (score 4):

May be you load the wrong lib file.Just like me，I get the same problem.But I can open AVI file in VC6.0 which use the opencv version 1.0.Finally，I find that I use the wrong lib.

In Debug Mode，but I use `opencv_core220.lib` and `opencv_highgui220.lib` .And I replace them with `opencv_core220d.lib` and `opencv_highgui220d.lib` .Now I can read it.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV 2.4.4 : there is only opencv_ffmpeg244.dll (release dll) and not opencv_ffmpeg244d.dll (debug dll)

So try in release compilation mode !

Comment: I've had the same missing DLL problem. The "release" version is working for me in both debug and release modes.

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter the same problem. With the sample code for VideoCapture, my visual studio program failed to open any video file. Then, the suggestion of nimcap works for me. "A missing OpenCV's ffmpeg.dll does not generate any warnings/errors in OpenCV 2.3.1, and code fails silently. Make sure that you have proper opencv_ffmpeg*.dll in your path."

Solution: Copy opencv_ffmpeg.dll to my visual studio project `/Debug` folder, I can open almost any video file with VideoCapture.

Answer (score 0):

Under **Windows x64**, you don't have to rename anything. Just put the following **...\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin** in your **PATH**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just adding on to this since I spent more time than I'd like to admit. Not being able to open the file caused a ton of strange exceptions.

If you find that absolute paths work, while relative paths don't work, another thing to check is to make sure that the working directory set properly.

In Visual Studio this is Project Properties (Configuration Properties) -> Debugging -> Working Directory. I found mine set to "$(ProjectDir)" by default when I really wanted "$(OutDir)".

Answer (score 0):

For those who didn't find the solution:
In openCV4 and "debug" mode follow these steps:

> Go to opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin

Copy "opencv_videoio_ffmpeg440_64.dll" to your debug folder of your project.

Answer (score -1):

You need to just download for your machine Xvid from xvid.org that's all: http://www.xvid.org/Downloads.15.0.html

Answer (score -1):

Just change your code from this:

```
VideoCapture capture("guitarplaying.avi");
```

to this:

```
CvCapture *input_video = cvCreateFileCapture("guitarplaying.avi");
```

Answer (score -1):

Open `D:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc14\bin` and copy the `opencv_ffmpeg320.dll` or `opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll` which is relevant for you based on your `Windows (x86 or x64)`.

`opencv_ffmpeg320.dll` -> for `32-bit Windows (x86)`

`opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll` -> for `64-bit Windows (x64)`

Paste the copied `.dll` to `C:\Python27\` or any location which is accessible from Windows `PATH` environment variables.

Alternatively, you could create a folder `D:\OpenCV\vendor\` and add `.dll` file to that folder and then add `D:\OpenCV\vendor\` to your `windows environment variables`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Ubuntu 16+, you can try this:

> pip install opencv-python