# Load Captures in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Which video formats can we use in OpenCV? Can anything in addition to AVI and load from camera be used?
If these are the only supported formats, is a video converter required to use other video formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how up-to-date it is, but [this OpenCV wiki page](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs) gives a good overview of what codecs are supported. If looks like AVI is the only format with decent cross-platform support. Your options are either to do the conversion using an external converter (like you suggest) or write code that uses a video library to load the image and create the appropriate `cv::Mat` or `IplImage *` header for the data.

Unless you're processing huge quantities of video I suggest taking the path of least resistance and just converting the videos to AVI (see the above link for the details of what OpenCV supports). Just be careful to avoid lossy compression: it will wreck havoc with a lot of image processing algoritms.

Comment: The linked wiki page is gone, but an archive is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130524095153/http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs).

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV "farms out" video encoding and decoding to other libraries (e.g., ffmpeg and VFW). Also, have a look at the `highgui` source [directory](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/modules/highgui/src/) to see all of the `VideoCapture` wrappers available (specifically pay attention to the `cap_*` implementations). AVI is merely a container, and really isn't that critical to what video codecs that OpenCV can read. AVI can contain several different combinations of video, audio, and even subtitle streams. See my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414947/why-cant-i-open-avi-video-in-opencv) about this. [Here](http://www.pitivi.org/manual/codecscontainers.html) is also a quick article explaining the differences between containers and codecs.

So, if you're on Linux make sure ffmpeg supports decoding the video codec you are interested in processing. You can check what codecs your version of ffmpeg supports with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -formats
```

On Windows, you'll want to make sure you have plenty of codecs available to decode various types of video like the [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/klcp_update.htm).