# How to read a video under OpenCV 3.0.0

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I am using win 8.1 and visual studio 2013 community. I download openCV3.0.0 from [here](http://opencv.org/). What I want to do is read a video. Following is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap("bb.mp4");
    if (!cap.isOpened()){
        std::cout << "Cannot open video!\n";
        return -1;
    }
    cv::Mat frame;
    while (cap.read(frame)){
        cv::imshow("frame", frame);
        char key = cv::waitKey(1) & 0xFF;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that `cap.isOpened()` always return false even I give an absolute path `cv::VideoCapture cap("D:\\bb.mp4")`. Following is another toy program that operates normally.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("aa.jpg");
    cv::imshow("img", img);
    char key = cv::waitKey(1) & 0xFF;
    return 0;
}
```

The second program shows that I can compile a program included openCV library correctly and also the path to the file should be correct since the aa.jpg and bb.mp4 are placed in the same folder. Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: Any error printed to console?

Comment: `Cannot open video!`, this is the only line /.\ Btw, I have the opencv 2.4.10 on my computer, I can use this function `cv::VideoCapture` with 2.4.10 on the other VS solution /.\

Comment: Double check if you added all required libraries as the other solution

Comment: Here is the list of lib I have under opencv 3.0.0 `opencv_ts300.lib
opencv_world300.lib`. Is that means I have to build the libraries by myself@@?

Comment: You may want to try it with an .avi container, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852514/list-file-extensions-supported-by-opencv.

Comment: can your program access the opencv_ffmpeg dll?