# VideoCapture always returns False in Python OPENCV [Linux]

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, opencv, ffmpeg

Every time that I use VideoCapture trying to access the frames from a video file, the return value (`ret`) is false. See the sample code below:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('asd.mkv')
    vid = []
    while True:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        if not ret: # Always happens
            break
        vid.append(cv2.resize(img, (171, 128)))
```

I have already tried absolutely everything I could find today by googling, including the [OpenCV guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) and [this long issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/121) on Github. Also, I read some solutions involving moving ffmpeg dll files, but that only was in the case of Windows.

Any ideas? Because I defenitely ran out of them.

Comment: Even though `ret` is false does `img` contain anything

Comment: Can you try providing a full qualified file path to `cv2.VideoCapture('full/path/to/vid.mkv')`

Comment: @chbchb55 No, it contains `None`. @ZdaR already tried that, and also different video formats.

Comment: Maybe it's writing directly to the file `'asd.mkv'`

Comment: @chbchb55 The method calls are to read the file.

Comment: I found your problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852514/list-file-extensions-supported-by-opencv, you can't use that format. The only format that VideoCapture works with is 'avi', 'mkv' isn't supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at my IDE (Visual Studio Code) and the association with bin files when installing OpenCV... my bad. [This](https://github.com/kratzert/Ubuntu_from_scratch/blob/master/Ubuntu_16_04LTS.md#installing-opencv3) guide worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference: installing opencv with pip does not work with ffmpeg.

From the [opencv-python FAQ](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python):

> Q: Why I can’t open video files on GNU/Linux distribution X or on macOS?
>
> A: OpenCV video I/O depends heavily on FFmpeg. Manylinux and macOS OpenCV binaries are not compiled against it. The purpose of these packages is to provide as easy as possible installation experience for OpenCV Python bindings and they should work directly out-of-the-box. Adding FFmpeg as an additional dependency without a “universal” FFmpeg build (e.g. LGPL licensed build like in the Windows wheels) the goal is considerably harder to achieve. This might change in the future.

Solutions:

1. [Build from source (docs)](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html). This worked for me.
2. [Use scikit-video as a workaround (Github)](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/121#issuecomment-55238785).

Comment: could you please explain what "compiled against" means? Does it mean we can install ffmpeg ourselves? or does it mean it has to be included in the opencv package

Comment: @AdamB I don't know the internals but it means OpenCV when compiling had to include ffmpeg to enable ffmpeg features. I believe you have to compile yourself with ffmpeg enabled.

Comment: A while ago I made a guide for ubuntu installing from source that may help https://askubuntu.com/a/1150443/477026

Comment: Great! I’ll try that out.