# can't open camera by index in Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolo, yolov4

I am using https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-custom-functions this repository. I want to crop and save pictures while running on webcam. I'm using Colab. But when I run the following code:

```
!python detect_video.py --weights ./checkpoints/yolov4-416 --size 416 --model yolov4 --video 0 --output ./detections/results2.avi --crop
```

then it says:

```
[ WARN:0@5.489] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (902) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
Video has ended or failed, try a different video format!
```

I know the problem is with opening the camera in Colab. But I couldn't find how to solve it.

Comment: Colab runs your code in a remote server, you cannot use your local webcam because it is literally not connected to the remote server.

Comment: I saw a Colab notebook like this:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xdjyBiY75MAVRSjgmiqI7pbRLn58VrbE?usp=sharing#scrollTo=UfaHiGn461oG
But I have no idea if this is adaptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're somehow able to use the webcam through Colab, make sure that the format of the video stream from your camera is supported by cv2.
I had a quick [look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20865122/14774959) and apparently only `.avi` is supported. So make sure that your input is in avi format.

Having a look at the `detect_video.py` file that you linked, the error raises in this piece of code:

```
# begin video capture
try:
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(int(video_path))
except:
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

...

while True:
    return_value, frame = vid.read()
    if return_value:
        ...
    else:
        print('Video has ended or failed, try a different video format!')
        break
```

This means that `cv2.VideoCapture()` is not able to read your input.