# How to open and process a video file like .mpeg or .avi using openCV's VideoCapture method in Java

Tags: java, opencv, file-processing

```
    import org.opencv.core.Core;        
    import org.opencv.core.Mat;        
    import org.opencv.core.Size;        
    import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;        
    import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;        
    import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;        

    public class Video        
    {        
        public static void main(String[] args)        
        {        
            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);        

    VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture(0);

    cap.open(1);

    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        System.out.println("No camera");
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Yes. Camera");
    }

    Mat frame = new Mat();
    cap.retrieve(frame);

    Highgui.imwrite("me1.jpg", frame);
    Mat frameBlur = new Mat();

    Imgproc.blur(frame, frameBlur, new Size(5,5));
    Highgui.imwrite("me2-blurred.jpg", frameBlur);

    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(frame, frameBlur, new Size(25, 25), 20);
    Highgui.imwrite("me3-blurred.jpg", frameBlur);

    cap.release();
        }
    }
```

---

I have used this code to open my Camera device and capture 3 different frames and made some operations on it. But, I couldn't open a file like .avi/.mpg/.mp4 etc., using {n_open} method of VideoCapture. There is a method in the VideoCapture implementation [here](http://enl.usc.edu/enl/trunk/aqua/OpenCV-2.3.1/src/org/opencv/highgui/VideoCapture.java). But because its a private and native method, that method can't be accesses using VideoCapture's object.

Could some one help how to do that using pure OpenCV 2.4.6 and Java
(Please **dont** suggest solution using **[Processing](http://processing.org/)** libraries)

Comment: Have you tried to open video file with `VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture("C:\\Somefile.avi");`? If this doesn't work, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414947/why-cant-i-open-avi-video-in-opencv

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on OpenCV `2.4.8`. The `VideoCapture` API has been extended of `public VideoCapture(String filename)` method.
The question remains why this feature has been implemented so late.

If using of recent version of OpenCV isn't acceptable for you for some reason, you have several options:

- Rebuild OpenCV by yourself with this method marked as public
- HACKY ONE: Make your copy of VideoCapture class (or  extend original one and play with reflection) with public `VideoCapture(String)` constructor. Then give support for native method `private static native long n_VideoCapture(java.lang.String filename)` by creating your own DLL using C++ OpenCV API. (**Tested**!)

Comment: The API has changed, but I still can't load any of my .avi, .mpeg (even tree.avi available in opencv, which does open while executing OpenCV c samples), in 2.4.7. Has any of you made it possible? Are you using some publicly available video? Kind regards,

Comment: Actually, it didn't work when using x86_64 but when using x86 it did work. It probably has got to do with loading ffmpeg dlls, but I haven't found exactly what it was...

Comment: That's right, in most of cases you have to deliver opencv_ffmpegXXX.dll. Take care of correct 32b/64b version and put it in some location from java library path (next to opencv_javaXXX.dll will be safe choice).

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem and this worked for me:

1. load the `ffmpeg` library

`System.loadLibrary("opencv_ffmpeg300_64");`

2. Open the file:

   `VideoCapture vC = new VideoCapture("res/video.mp4");`
3. Copy `opencv_ffmpeg300_64.dll` from `opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin` to
   `opencv\build\java\x64`

*Please note* that `64` and `.dll` may differ from an OS to another, those are for `Windows x64`