# Cannot open RTSP videostream with OpenCV in Java

Tags: java, opencv, rtsp

I am using openCV to process RTSP video stream in Java. The stream has address

```
rtsp://stream.c-budejovice.cz:1935/cam/Axis240.stream
```

I can connect to it in Python or VLC player, so address is correct. But my Java code

```java
String rtspUrl = "rtsp://stream.c-budejovice.cz:1935/cam/Axis240.stream";
// Initialize video capture object
VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture(rtspUrl);

System.out.println(videoCapture.isOpened());
```

Ends with "False". I also added some sleep time after `new VideoCapture(rtspUrl)`, but it did not help.

Problem is that there is no error message when opening the video.

Edit on request of @ChristophRackwitz

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.9.0
=====================================
  Version control:               v4.9.0-0

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2023-12-28T18:50:29Z
    Host:                        Linux 5.15.0-1053-azure x86_64
    CMake:                       3.28.1
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               RELEASE

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (14 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (8 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (34 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (5 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 9.4.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf zlib ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann highgui imgcodecs imgproc java ml objdetect photo stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    gapi world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 python2 python3 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         YES

  GUI:                           NONE
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.3)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
      SIMD Support Request:      YES
      SIMD Support:              NO
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.5.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      NO
      avcodec:                   NO
      avformat:                  NO
      avutil:                    NO
      swscale:                   NO
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2021.10.0 [2021.10.0]
           at:                   /home/runner/work/opencv/opencv/opencv-4.9.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2021.10.0)
              at:                /home/runner/work/opencv/opencv/opencv-4.9.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
    VA:                          NO
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)
    Flatbuffers:                 builtin/3rdparty (23.5.9)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /home/runner/work/opencv/opencv/opencv-4.9.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python3

  Java:                          export all functions
    ant:                         /bin/ant (ver 1.10.7)
    Java:                        NO
    JNI:                         /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.392/x64/include /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.392/x64/include/linux /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.392/x64/include
    Java wrappers:               YES (ANT)
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /usr/local
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: call OpenCV's `getBuildInformation()` and add the output to your question

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz

what exactly should I be lloking for there? There is a lot of info. The library version is  Version control:               v4.9.0-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load video in OpenCV (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71812108/how-to-load-video-in-opencv-java)

Comment: [edit] and paste it all.

Comment: @drdrej unfortunately not. It is windows solution with dll. I am using linux and getting problem with getting right libraries. And as Christopher said: it is about files, not streams.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz ok, I added the rest.

Comment: yup, video I/O section is completely gutted. without gstreamer or ffmpeg, you won't be able to read any rtsp streams (or even just video files... apart from MJPEG in .AVI, which is built-in). I don't know which of those you'll need. both, standalone, should be able to read rtsp streams. I think OpenCV prefers ffmpeg here. you'll want to hunt for recipes on the internet for how to get opencv for java to also have ffmpeg abilities. I'm positive that there are solutions either on SO or on the opencv forum.

Answer (score 0):

Bases on advice in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78165571/cannot-open-rtsp-videostream-with-opencv-in-java/78177084#comment137810293_78165571) by [@ChristophRackwitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602877/christoph-rackwitz) and `getBuildInformation()`, I found out that my Video I/O was empty. Thus I have to get correct build.